# Comparing two columns and replace in R Package

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, replace, compare

I have a problem with using for loop. My problem is: if two columns are equal (have 176 or 184 or 180 or 182 or 163 or 167 value) replace two columns =NULL

I wrote script, but it doesn't work.

```
for (i in dane.dzikie$REN75M10 && dane.dzikie$REN75M10.1) if (i==176 | 184 | 180 | 182 |
                                                          163 | 167) {i=NULL}
```

It is a part of my data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkalc.png)

I would like to replace the first, fifth and last columns should be replace for NA because both columns contain 176 or 184 or 180 or 182 or 163 or 167 value. The condition is a the same value in both columns.

Comment: Please read up on how to ask and on how to provide a reproducible example. Bear in mind that R is vectorized. For-loops are not the answer most of the time.

Comment: Also, you can't use `|` as "or" for numbers (or `&&` for whatever those variables are), only for things that are already Booleans. Instead, use `i %in% c(176, 184, ...)`. And you can't (easily) put `NULL` in a data.frame; you probably mean `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# example dataframe something like this?
dane.dzikie <- data.frame(REN75M10=c(176, 184, 5, 6, 7), 
                          REN75M10.1=c(163,1,2,3,4), OTHER=c(163,2,3,4,5))

columns=c("REN75M10", "REN75M10.1")
invalid.values <- c(176,184,180,182,163,167)
dane.dzikie[,columns] <- 
   apply(dane.dzikie[,columns], 2, 
         function(x) ifelse(x %in% invalid.values, NA, x))
```

Comment: It is similar to my problem, but It  should look like this:  if I have in rows two values e.g. 176 it should replace for NA. Only if 176 is in two columns in the same row.